# Homeomorphism in compact two dimensional manifold, periodic points, and Euler Characteristic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

I want to prove that if a homeomorphism (a continuous bijection with continuous inverse) in a two dimensional manifold doesn't have a periodic point, then the Euler Characteristc of the manifold is zero.

In other words, if $M$ is a two dimensional compact manifold, and there exist a homeomorphism $h: M\longrightarrow M$ such that $h$ doesn't have a periodic point, then $\chi(M)=0$.

It implies for instance that a homeomorphism on a sphere always have periodic points.

Comment: What do you mean by a periodic point?  If $\tau: S^2 \to S^2$ is the antipode map on the sphere, then $\tau^2(x) = x$ for all $x \in S^2$, so wouldn't this mean that $\tau$ has periodic points?

Comment: Yes, it has a periodic point. A periodic point for $h$ is a $x$ in the domain such that there exist an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $h^{n}(x)=x$.

Comment: The comment of @JHF refers, perhaps, to your final sentence. Did you mean to say that a homeomorphism on a sphere *always* has periodic points?

Comment: One could apply the Lefschtez fixed point theorem to this situation. Assuming that $h$ preserves orientation, one could conclude that if $T \in \text{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$ is a matrix representing the induced homology homomorphism $f_* : H_1(M;\mathbb Z) \to H_1(M;\mathbb Z)$, then $\text{trace}(T^k)=2$ for all $k \ge 1$. This must have strong consequences... for instance if it implied that $T$ is the identity then you would be done.

Comment: As a follow-up to Lee Mosher's argument, the condition on the traces of the powers implies that there are exactly two nonzero eigenvalues for $T$, both equal to $1$.  Since $T$ is invertible, this means that the rank of $H_1$ is $2$, so that the Euler characteristic is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your comments unfortunately I am not able of understand your arguments (The Lefschtez fixed point theorem for example). I thought it will be more easy. Maybe some of you can guarantee that this is true?. it needs some other condition like orientation in the manifold?

Comment: @Gil Do you mean to say you don't know the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, or rather how it was applied here? It is essentially the perfect tool for the job, being created to compare topological information about a space (and a map) to its fixed points. That in mind, the best approach is probably "learn about Lefschetz." If you don't want to do that, you should probably say here what background you have and the kind of techniques you would consider permissible in an answer.

Comment: Mike Miller I don't understand what the Lefschetz fixed point theorem says and neither it's application on this problem, maybe later I studied it, can you give me a reference, where I can learn homology and that stuff. 

I was thinking about the Poincaré–Hopf theorem.

Comment: You will find the Lefschetz fixed point theorem in almost any algebraic topology book. For example, in Hatcher's book it is found in Section 2.C. It is certainly interesting to compare the Poincare-Hopf theorem with the Lefschetz theorem, because they exist in different but overlapping settings. The Poincare-Hopf theorem is about vector fields, i.e. flows, i.e. smooth actions of $\mathbb R$; whereas the Lefschetz theorem is about self-homeomorphisms, i.e. topological actions of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your very useful your comments